# Using Jquery plugin Database Tables - How do I prevent additional footers and headers from being added to the bottom of the table

Tags: jquery, datatables, header, footer

I have destroy set to true as a way to possibly prevent additional headers and footers from being created.  This does not work.  Other than the the additional footers and headers, the table is fine.

Comment: **additional footers and headers** means?

Comment: [Please read ho to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: An additional table row containing the header and footer is being created and added to the bottom of the table.

Comment: Share your jquery and html code to?

Comment: just remove<thead> and  <tfoot> part to remove header and footers

Comment: Problem was resolved.  Issue was that I wasn't emptying the table each time it was being created on click.  Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Can you show us how your table looks like?